# How can I override the font in java.awt.Component with Scala?

Tags: java, scala, fonts, components, overriding

I tried

```
scala> class Foo extends Component { var font = new java.awt.Font("Helvetica", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12) }
```

and I got:

```
<console>:10: error: overriding variable font in class Component of type java.awt.Font;
 variable font needs `override' modifier
       class Foo extends Component { var font = new java.awt.Font("Helvetica", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12) }
                                         ^
```

So I tried

```
scala> class Foo extends Component { override var font = java.awt.new Font("Helvetica", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12) }
```

but this didn't help at all:

```
<console>:10: error: overriding variable font in class Component of type java.awt.Font;
 variable font has incompatible type
       class Foo extends Component { override var font = new java.awt.Font("Helvetica", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12) }
                                                  ^
```

What's the reason behind this error and how should it be done correctly?

**EDIT: Sorry, didn't saw that scala also has `Component`. The `Component` in question is the one from `java.awt.Component`!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Component contains getters and setters for `font`, so the canonical way to set the font is:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  font = new java.awt.Font(/* blah blah */)
}
```

If you want to override the font defs to use a var, <strike>you have to use something compatible with `scala.swing.Font`, which wraps the Java fonts (normally done with implicit conversions).  Like so:</strike>

```
class Foo extends Component {
  override var font: scala.swing.Font =
    new java.awt.Font("Helvetica", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 12)
}
```

I'm not sure this will do what you want.  (Edit: tested in a REPL session with too much junk loaded; you don't actually need to do this!  The simple override var font = new java.awt.Font thing works.)  The normal getter/setter is designed to pass the information on through to the `javax.swing` peer.  If you do it this way, you'll probably break that forwarding.  So use the first method.

---

Edit if you are trying to do this in a `java.awt.Component`: `Font font;` is a private field in `java.awt.Component`.  You can't override fields in Java, and you can't do *anything* with private fields in Java.  So trying to override it with a new var is guaranteed to not work.  (The compiler could certainly give a more informative error message, however!)  Scala can only override fields because they're not really fields--they're a getter/setter pair referring to a hidden underlying field.

You should use (or override) `getFont` and `setFont` instead.

Comment: +1 Sometimes those implicit conversions really result in weird error messages ...

Comment: @x3ro - Indeed.  But sometimes you think a thing should work one way, but it actually works a different way, and then you also get error messages that seem really weird until you realize that it doesn't work the way you thought.  This, I think, falls into the latter case--"variable font has incompatible type" seems perfectly clear to me.  It's saying, "You thought it was a java.awt.Font and it isn't."

Comment: Well I got something like " overriding variable font in class Component of type java.awt.Font; method font has incompatible type", even if I specified font:java.awt.Font . That is pretty unclear for me. Or maybe I'm not getting your point here^^